Alternate Civil War: The USA and the Confederate States of America (CSA) against England
My grandfather once told me about a book he read where the British accidentally landed on a bit of confederate land and accidentally started a fight. Then the USA army in the area came to the rescue of the confederates, apparently finding more in common with the rebels over the brits.
I can't locate the book. Does anyone recognize it?

This sounds like Stars and Stripes Forever by Harry Harrison, the first book of a trilogy.
Kirkus Reviews touches upon the key points you mentioned:

Harrison travels the high-traffic American Civil War thoroughfare.
Here, as in real-world history, the Civil War is already under way
when the captain of a US warship removes two Confederate bigwigs from
a British vessel in international waters.
Thereafter, matters diverge: in reality, a furious and minatory
British diplomatic retort was toned down by Queen Victoria’s beloved
Prince Consort, Albert; in Harrison’s version, Albert dies before he
can rewrite the dispatch, leaving President Lincoln facing a senseless
war with Britain.
Meanwhile, thanks to several key changes in personnel, the Union’s
armed forces gain better equipment and grow stronger. In due course,
British forces, massing in Canada, invade: predictably so, since their
inflexible and conservative tactics are designed to wage not merely
the previous war of 1812 but the Revolutionary War. At the same time,
the iron-built Monitor and the ironclad Virginia duly clash in Hampton
Roads, rendering almost the entire British Navy obsolete.
Finally, a British force sent to break the Union blockade of the Gulf
Coast accidentally attacks and destroys a Confederate stronghold,
leaving the British commander-in-chief, the Duke of Cambridge, with no
alternative (as he sees it) but to mount a full scale invasion of the
CSA as well. Naturally, when attacked by a common enemy, the USA and
CSA set aside their differences to deal with this new threat.


This is what I thought of the instant I saw the question title pop up in HNQ. I own the first couple books, but it starts out ridiculous, and quickly jumps the shark as they just seem to sort of forget the whole slavery issue, and start focusing on freeing Ireland from the British. It's... nuts (and I actually like a lot of Harry Harrison's other stuff).

Sounds reasonable. I'm going to check it out and if that ends up being right, I'll give you the check mark. Thanks!
